# Let $<x,y>=x^tJ\bar y$ and $(L_A)^*=L_B$

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

In $\mathbb C^2$, assume that $<x,y>=x^tJ\bar y$ is an inner product. For $A \in M_{2\times 2} (\mathbb C)$, let $(L_A)^*=L_B$ where $L_A$ is the linear transformation of $\mathbb C^2$  such that $L_A \begin{pmatrix}
        z_1  \\
        z_2  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
=A \begin{pmatrix}
        z_1  \\
        z_2  \\
        \end{pmatrix}$
 and $(L_A)^*$ is its adjoint with respect to the given scalar product.

(a) When $J$ is the identity matrix, show that B=A*.

(b) When $J=
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & i  \\
        -i & 2  \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$, find the explicit form of B.

What I want to know:

(a) Is it $B=A^*=I$? Do  I have to choose a basis to show this?

(b) I don't have the faintest idea how to start. Would you give me a basic guideline to find the form of B?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I suppose that $L_A$ is the linear transformation of $\mathbb C^2$ given by $$L_A\begin{bmatrix} z_1 \\ z_2 \end{bmatrix} = A\begin{bmatrix} z_1 \\ z_2 \end{bmatrix},$$
and that $L_A^\star$ is its adjoint with respect to the given scalar product, right? (You should specify such things in your question)

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Assuming that your notation is as I guessed in my comment above,) 
Write 
$$
\left\langle L_Ax , y \right\rangle = x^t A^t J \overline y, $$ 
and, denoting with $\overline B$ the entrywise complex conjugation, 
$$\left\langle x, L_B y \right\rangle = x^t J\overline B \overline y.$$ 
For $L_B=L_A^\star$ you need that the right hand sides of those expressions be equal. Since $x, y\in\mathbb C^2$ are arbitrary, this can only happen if...

Proceeding this way you can find an explicit expression for the matrix $B$ associated to $L_A^\star$. This expression should reduce to something familiar when $J$ is the identity matrix.

(These things arise in [Lorentzian geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_space), where one usually has $J=\mathrm{diag}(+1, -1\ldots -1)$ or $J=\mathrm{diag}(-1, +1\ldots +1)$).